# Springboot, springfox, more than one API

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

I have one application with Springboot (1.3.0), Springfox-swagger2 (2.2.2) and Springfox-swagger-ui (2.2.2). I have configured two APIs, on of them show the docs of some services in certain paths (/my-root/internal.*) and in the other the rest of the paths (/my-root/external.*).

My problema is that I have one ApiModel (lets said "Transaction") shared between one service in "internal.*" and one in "external.*" and I want to show a property of "Transaction" in the internal api doc but hide in external api doc.

Do you know how I can do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is currently not possible as of [springfox 2.5.0](http://springfox.io)